# Read from multiple ports simultaneously in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, port, real-time

I'm trying to read data from three devices simultaneously (2 devices works at 100 Hz and the 3rd at 2000 Hz) and plot the data in real-time using one timer. I'm using 'BytesAvailableFcn' for each port.

When I'm working with each of them separately my code works fine and display the graph perfect but when I'm trying to read from 2 or 3 together I receive odd data and get delays in my plotting.

I think the problem is that the ports interrupt each other. Does anyone have a solution for this problem? by the way I'm not using multi-thread, should I use parallel processing?

Thanks, Nir

Comment: Don't use the `ByteAvailableFcn` trigger on 3 different devices for _plotting_, they will for sure interfere with each other. If you want to probe multiple device as described, better to "pull" the data at a given interval (for ex. a timer every 100ms) and plot all the data points retrieved. Make sure your serial port buffers are large enough to hold all the data between two retrieval.

Comment: Thanks,
I'm using 'ByteAvailableFcn' to get the data from each port and the 'Timer' function for plotting all three of them.
Is there a way to make sure the interrupts don't interfere each other while reading the data or should I use the 'timer' to read and then plot at each "pulse"? Because I'm not sure my devices have enough memory to hold data for that long.

Comment: Your devices don't have to have memory. Set the [`InputBufferSize`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/inputbuffersize.html) of each serial port to a number sufficient to hold ~1s of data (at their respective frequency), set the [`ReadAsyncMode`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/readasyncmode.html) property to `continuous`. In your timer routine: read each serial port (what is in the input buffer, you can get the size from the [`BytesAvailable`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/bytesavailable.html) property), then plot.